# Maintaining responsiveness with div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I inherited the site ironcowboy.co that is having issues with the section that has the email submit form  and the text "Get updates on the journey".  Right now there is js on the text and form to delay loading.  What needs to happen is that lines just needs to follow the text and video above as it is resizing.  This is definitely not my forte but it seems that every time I try to manipulate it, it gets out of alignment.

The goal is to get the line of text and the form centered so that it will stay in the center as the screen is resized. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide any form of images, code and/or working examples to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Basically if you resize the screen horizontally on the homepage at www.ironcowboy.co the line that says "get updates about the journey and the form to submit your email will not stay centered. Let me know if you cant see if because alot of the content hasnt been loading on the server for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most messy hacky css hack I've written in some time but the html is a mess so actually cleaning it up and writing proper css would take quite some time :P

Here's the css:

```
#subscribebox {
  width: 680px !important;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  display: block !important;
}
#subscribebox input[type="text"] {
  margin: 0 0 0 340px !important;
  width: 258px !important;
}
#subscribebox input[type="submit"] {
  width: 80px !important;
  margin: -50px 0 0 240px !important;
}
#subscribebox p {
  left: 0 !important;
  float: left; !important;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect!  I have no idea why but sometimes the background video slider doesnt resize to the correct full screen height when you load the page.  Did that happen to you?

Comment: Sorry I am an idiot lol is there a way to flip them so the paragraph is first?

Comment: I edited the code to switch the positions, haven't tested the code since I'm on my phone so the edited code is just a wild guess :P

Comment: And yes that video bg is sometimes buggy here too, I'll look into it tomorrow.